# How can i append data to existing xml value in sql server 2008

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

I have a table called student.

`Table Student(
Name varchar()
,subject xml)`

I have some values in my data database. Now i have a requirement to append the xml data.

```
<subject code="Maths">
  <subjectname name="test">test123</subjectname>
</subject>
```

i want to add a new value to the existing xml.

```
<subjectname name="newtest">newtest123</subjectname>
```

this will be the sample value.
Any one have any idea or way to approach the problem any work around on the same.

Answer (score 1):

`update Student
set subject.modify('insert <subjectname name="newtest">newtest123</subjectname> as last into /Maths[1]')
where name='YourName';`

Dird